# Flask-Session + redis + gunicorn new session for every browser

Tags: python, session, redis, gunicorn, flask-login

I'm using Flask-Session and redis for an application im trying to make and im using gunicorn with 4 gevent workers as the production server.
http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/

I'm trying to build a counter which should have a seperate session id each time a new browser or tab is opened and each session id is supposed to maintain its own count.

Here's the code that i have till now.

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask.json import jsonify
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
import redis
import os


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = '123456789012345678901234'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
    app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url('localhost:6379')
    # app.config.from_object(__name__)

    sess = Session()
    sess.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/set/')
    def set():
        session['key'] = 1
        return 'ok'

    @app.route('/get/')
    def get():
        session['key'] = session.get('key','not set') + 1
        return 'Count: '+ str(session.get('key','not set')) + ', Process ID:'+str(os.getpid())

    return app
```

In the 'set' route, im setting the key value to 1 and whenever i go to 'get' the counter value increases.